# How to concatenate every four lines for the first four lines of a file

Tags: bash, perl, unix, text

I'm not sure the best wording to ask this question, but I'm trying to concatenate the first four lines to the next four lines and so on until the end of the file.

My data looks like:

```
aggaacgtgagttgaaaattgaagcgacaaacttggtttcatgtcctgtttgtggaaaga
catctattgttagagacaatatattgtctgatctgacttatctgcatgttc---------
 .     **    ..* * *. * .* * .*..**..**  .  * ****.         

gcataaaaggaatggacacaatcataaatgaacatcttgatatctgccttacaagaaggt
----------tgtggattcctttctttttccttttggagatatctgccttacaagaaggt
           .****. *  *. *   *   . *   **********************

ccaaacgaaaacttacccaacgcacactacttcagtttggtgttggatcaagtaccaaaa
ccaaacgaaaacttacccaacgcacactacttcagtttggtgttggatcaagtaccaaaa
************************************************************
```

And I'm trying to merge/concatenate every four lines to the four lines before to create a horizontal file format that looks like:

```
aggaacgtgagttgaaaattgaagcgacaaacttggtttcatgtcctgtttgtggaaagagcataaaaggaatggacacaatcataaatgaacatcttgatatctgccttacaagaaggtccaaacgaaaacttacccaacgcacactacttcagtttggtgttggatcaagtaccaaaa
catctattgttagagacaatatattgtctgatctgacttatctgcatgttc-------------------tgtggattcctttctttttccttttggagatatctgccttacaagaaggtccaaacgaaaacttacccaacgcacactacttcagtttggtgttggatcaagtaccaaaa
 .     **    ..* * *. * .* * .*..**..**  .  * ****.                    .****. *  *. *   *   . *   **********************************************************************************
```

I know I can use `paste - -` to delete a newline character every other line, but what would be the simplest route to paste together the different lines of my file for the first four lines every other four lines?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with `awk`? Concatenate each line to a variable until NR is a multiple of 4. Then print the variable and clear the variable to start the next block.

Comment: Even simpler: Just print the current line without a newline after it. When NR is a multiple of 4, print a newline as well.

Comment: @Barmar I think the OP want the output to be 3 (or 4, this is not 100% clear) different lines, the first being the concatenation of input lines 1, 5, 9..., the second being the concatenation of input lines 2, 6, 10...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;                   # hash container to store the lines

while(<>) {                  # read lines from stdin
    chomp;                   # remove newline
    my $idx = ($. - 1) % 4;  # calculate index of line [0,4)
    $lines{$idx} .= $_;      # concatename the current line to what's at $idx
}

# Done, print the result:
for(my $i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
    print $lines{$i} ."\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice! As a nasty one-liner: `perl -lnE '$a[($.-1)%4].=$_ }{ say for @a' file`

Comment: @rowboat Beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to store each line in an array to be printed at the end:

```sh
awk -v n=4 '
{ a[NR]=$0 }
END {
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for (j=i; j<=NR; j+=n) {
      printf "%s", a[j]
    }
    print ""
  }
}' file
```

Another way is to read the file 4 times (this avoids storing the entire file in memory):

```sh
awk -v n=4 '
  FNR==1 {
    if (c++) print ""
  }
  ! ((NR-c)%n) { printf "%s", $0 }
  END {
    if (c) print ""
  }
' file file file file
```

This could be done using a shell loop:

```sh
for c in 1 2 3 4
do
  awk '! ((NR-c)%n)' n=4 c="$c" ORS= file
  echo
done
```

Output from any of the above will be:

```
aggaacgtgagttgaaaattgaagcgacaaacttggtttcatgtcctgtttgtggaaagagcataaaaggaatggacacaatcataaatgaacatcttgatatctgccttacaagaaggtccaaacgaaaacttacccaacgcacactacttcagtttggtgttggatcaagtaccaaaa
catctattgttagagacaatatattgtctgatctgacttatctgcatgttc-------------------tgtggattcctttctttttccttttggagatatctgccttacaagaaggtccaaacgaaaacttacccaacgcacactacttcagtttggtgttggatcaagtaccaaaa
 .     **    ..* * *. * .* * .*..**..**  .  * ****.                    .****. *  *. *   *   . *   **********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the last two methods to work with piped output?

Answer (score 1):

It seems every three lines are separated by a blank line. If this is the case, this `awk` program might be what you're looking for:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = ""; FS = "\n" }
           { for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) line[i] = line[i] $i }
     END   { for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) print line[i] }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is huge storing its whole content in variables or processing it several times could lead to memory or performance issues. Generating 4 different files on the fly and concatenating them together could then help. Example with GNU `awk` in a `bash` script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# file myScript.sh

unset tmpdir
trap 'rm -rf -- "$tmpdir"' EXIT TERM

declare input="${1:--}"
declare tmpdir

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1
awk -v t="$tmpdir" '
{
  printf("%s", $0) > t "/file." (NR-1)%4 ".part"
}
END {
  for(i=0; i<4; i++) print "" > t "/file." i ".part"
}' "$input"
cat "$tmpdir"/file.{0..3}.part
```

The script uses a temporary directory to store the 4 intermediate files. A trap deletes the temporary directory upon normal termination or if the script is terminated before its normal end. Usage: `./myScript.sh [FILE]`. With no `FILE`, or when `FILE` is `-`, the script reads the standard input.

Comment: Does this work with piped output?

Comment: What do you mean with _piped output_? You want to pipe the result to something else? If yes, just replace ` > file.new.txt` with `| <something else>`.

Comment: Like `function <something else> | awk ...` because the `cat` and `rm` commands can't be utilized if I try to pipe output into the awk script currently?

Comment: I see. I edited my answer to show a complete bash script that takes its input from a file or the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` script will do the change

```
awk '
{
    line = (line == "" ? $0 : line$0);
    if (++i == 4) {
        print line;
        i = 0; line="";
    }
}
END {
    if (line != "")
        print line;
}'
```

you can add filenames to the `awk` command to process several files or read from the standard input as the command is shown.  You can add a separator char between `line` and `$0` if you want the lines separated by some string, or change the `4` for the number of lines you want together.  For example to group the lines in groups of three, and separate them by `@` characters:

```
awk '
{
    line = (line == "" ? $0 : line"@"$0);
    if (++i == 3) {
        print line;
        i = 0; line="";
    }
}
END {
    if (line != "")
        print line;
}'
```